# Setting TextField focus in macOS SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, textfield

I’ve built a simple macOS modal dialog in SwiftUI that takes some text from the user:

[image]

This is presented via Storyboard Segue from a menu item to an `NSWindowController` that contains an `NSHostingController`:

```swift
class
OpenLocationController: NSHostingController<OpenLocationView>
{
    @objc
    required
    dynamic
    init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        let view = OpenLocationView()
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: view)
    }
}

struct
OpenLocationView : View
{
    @State private var location: String = ""

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            HStack
            {
                Text("Location:")
                TextField("https://", text: $location) { self.openLocation() }
            }

            HStack
            {
                Spacer()
                Button("Cancel") { self.dismiss() }
                Button("Open") { self.simulateClick() }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(minWidth: 500.0)
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the Storyboard:

[image]

I’d like to automatically focus the text field and select all the text in it when the dialog is displayed. I’d also like the Tab key to focus to it (for some reason, that doesn't work either, although that would be moot if I could just focus it on display). How would I do this in SwiftUI?

Comment: In my env TextField is focused by default (actually it is native macOS feature).

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be the case for me. In my case, I'm presenting the dialog via a segue in a Storyboard. I updated the question with more code.